# Could not get status from Metro bundler. read ECONNRESET

Tags: android, react-navigation, expo

Every thing was working fine, when I run this command I'll get the following error:

/> expo start

[10:23:11] Starting project at D:\projects\app1
[10:23:11] Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
[10:23:11] Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
[10:23:17] Starting Metro Bundler on port 19001.
[10:23:45] Downloading latest version of Expo
/[10:23:45] Could not get status from Metro bundler. read ECONNRESET
[10:23:45] Connecting to Metro bundler failed.
[10:23:45] Error: Connecting to Metro bundler failed.
    at C:\xdl@53.0.1\src\Project.js:1375:11
    at Generator.throw ()
    at step (C:\Users\ersha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\Project.js:2236:191)
    at C:\Users\ersha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\Project.js:2236:402
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

**what I have done so far**

remove the note_modules

run yarn install

I have also tried it with Admin privileges

**what am I using**

Windows 10 Home

Windows Terminal

Android Emulator

Has anyone come up with a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The port 19002 was used by another application, I had to stop the service and then every thing worked fine. easy fix but took me 1 hour to find it. I hope It could save time for others

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same situation. I entered `/etc/hosts` and added `127.0.0.1:1900 localhost`. And I was able to use `yarn start`. I'm not sure if I previously had using `expo start --lan` influenced what I later changed `/etc/hosts` to do so. But after all, I was able to run the app and compile JavaBundle...
See how this worked correctly and other possible options from other users at: https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/52#issuecomment-564616512.